# How to enable GPT features like ask-to-viz in PyGWalker?

Tags: python, visualization, openai-api

In [PyGWalker](https://github.com/Kanaries/pygwalker), there is an ["ask" button](https://kanaries.net/home/pygwalker) on the top of the UI, it seems it can enable user visualize their data with asking question in natural language. But how to setup pygwalker to enable this feature.

[image]

Comment: Is this a self-promotion? (It is a very cool library you got there, the feature is good and this QA is good)

Comment: Yes, I am the maintainer of pygwalker. There are lots of users asking about how to use ask feature but they are not familiar with [asking quesitons in github](https://github.com/Kanaries/pygwalker/issues). So I am creating some common questions in stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 1):

PyGWalker's GPT features requires a Kanaries API key to be enabled.

Here is step-by-step guidence of how to setup Kanaries API key.

1. Signup / Login into Kanaries website and create an account.
2. Install pygwalker with `pip install pygwalker`
3. Use pygwalker's command line tool to login pygwalker

```bash
pygwalker login
```

After you login in command line, pygwalker will setup the access token for using gpt features automatically.